# How do I select column based on value in another column with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame looks like this:

```
  id  A  T C  G ref var
1  1 10 15 7  0   A   C
2  2 11  9 2  3   A   G
3  3  2 31 1 12   T   C
```

I'd like to create two new columns: `ref_count` and `var_count` which will have following values:

1. Value from `A` column and value from `C` column, since `ref` is `A` and `var` is `C`
2. Value from `A` column and value from `G` column, since `ref` is `A` and `var` is `G`

etc.

So I'd like to select a column based on the value in another column for each row.

Thanks!

Comment: The rules are not clear to me.  Sorry

Comment: @akrun sorry for the confusion, I updated the question.

Comment: Perhaps you want `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = A:G) %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(name == ref|name == var) %>% mutate(nm1 = c('ref_count', 'var_count')) %>% ungroup %>%  select(id, value, nm1) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = value) %>% left_join(df1, .)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` to reshape into 'long' format, `filter` the rows and then reshape it to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = A:G) %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(name == ref|name == var) %>%
   mutate(nm1 = c('ref_count', 'var_count')) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(id, value, nm1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = value) %>%
   left_join(df1, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 9
#     id     A     T     C     G ref   var   ref_count var_count
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1    10    15     7     0 A     C            10         7
#2     2    11     9     2     3 A     G            11         3
#3     3     2    31     1    12 T     C            31         1
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can also make use  of the vectorized row/column indexing

```
df1$refcount <- as.matrix(df1[2:5])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), match(df1$ref,  names(df1)[2:5]))]
df1$var_count <- as.matrix(df1[2:5])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), match(df1$var,  names(df1)[2:5]))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, A = c(10, 11, 2), T = c(15, 9, 31), 
    C = c(7, 2, 1), G = c(0, 3, 12), ref = c("A", "A", "T"), 
    var = c("C", "G", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a `tidyverse` alternative without creating a long dataframe that needs filtering. It essentially uses `tidyr::nest()` to nest the dataframe by rows, after which the correct column can be selected for each row.

```r
df1 %>% 
    nest(data = -id) %>% 
    mutate(
        data = map(
            data,
            ~mutate(., refcount = .[[ref]], var_count = .[[var]])
        )
    ) %>% 
    unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 9
#>      id     A     T     C     G ref   var   refcount var_count
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1    10    15     7     0 A     C           10         7
#> 2     2    11     9     2     3 A     G           11         3
#> 3     3     2    31     1    12 T     C           31         1
```

A variant of this does not need the (assumed row-specific) `id` column but defines the nested groups from the unique values of `ref` and `var` directly:

```r
df1 %>% 
    nest(data = -c(ref, var)) %>% 
    mutate(
        data = pmap(
            list(data, ref, var),
            function(df, ref, var) {
                mutate(df, refcount = df[[ref]], var_count = df[[var]])
            }
        )
    ) %>% 
    unnest(data)
```

The data were specified by akrun:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, A = c(10, 11, 2), T = c(15, 9, 31), 
    C = c(7, 2, 1), G = c(0, 3, 12), ref = c("A", "A", "T"), 
    var = c("C", "G", "C")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```